# Microsoft outlook 2010 data files

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have 3 email accounts showing in Account settings under the data file tab. Two are Comcast, one of which is my Comcast primary that is checked as the default, the other a secondary. The 3rd is a iCloud email.

The one checked as the default email isn't listed under the the email tab. The one secondary email set up with Comcast is.

How do I get it added to the email tab.

Answer (score 0):

Little explanation first.

**Data Files Tab**
Outlook uses a data file to store data. You can have a data file without having any email account associated to it or listed on the email tab. An example of this would be the Archive data file.

**Email Tab**
The email tab is a listing of accounts setup to be used by outlook to send and receive email.  You can have none or many different emails setup here. These put the received messages into one of the data files listed in on the data tab.

To answer your question, you just need to add an account to your profile. This is done through the `Control Panel > Mail` applet.

1. Go to `Control Panel`
2. Type `Mail` in the search box
3. Click the `Mail` icon
4. Click the `Show Profiles` button
5. Choose the profile you want the new email associated with
6. Click `Properties`
7. Now on the Email tab choose `New`
8. Follow the prompts to add the account

The reason for the order of the steps is to add to an existing data file. Otherwise, Outlook will likely add yet another data file if you add the account from within Outlook.

More [detailed information](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-an-email-account-by-using-advanced-settings-df811069-5942-47d4-9197-0ff14e904b31#bm2b) available here.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answered your question, please accept it by selecting the check mark on the left. This will indicate to other users the question is answered. Of course, if it does not answer your question, feedback would be appreciated.